# Seeking Help in Understanding Spring / Hibernate Datasources and Transaction Managers

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, c3p0

My project uses Spring and Hibernate to manage the database and its transactions. I used HibernateTransactionManager to manger the transactions along side with Hibernate's SessionFactory. Everything works very well.

I want to experiment using other transaction managers e.g. Spring's DataSourceTransactionManager. The experiment failed. Then I layered Spring's TransactionAwareDataSource on top of the C3P0 data source and everything was working again.

The short answer, as I read in the Spring Tx docs, is to make the datasources tx aware. Why do we need to make the datasource transaction aware then only the tx managers can manage them which is not in the case with Hibernates SessionFactory and HibernateTransactionManager?

Thanks